# calling method with C# in node.js module by the help of edge.js

Tags: c#, node.js, edge.js

I'm trying to use [edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) for using a node.js module within C#.

I can access a property of the module, but not a method.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EdgeJs;

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start().Wait();
    }

    public static async Task Start()
    {
        var func = Edge.Func(@"return require('../require.js')");
        var invoke = func.Invoke(new { });
        var require = (dynamic)invoke.Result;

        Console.WriteLine(require.answer1); // answer 1

        var deleg = require.answer2;
        Console.WriteLine(deleg);
        var task = deleg.Invoke(1); 
        Console.WriteLine(task);

        // var result = await task.Run(); // error
        // Console.WriteLine(result);


    }

}
```

require.js

```
module.exports = function (data, callback) {
    var module = require('./module');
    var result = module;
    callback(null, result);
};
```

module.js

```
exports.answer1 = "answer 1";
exports.answer2 = function () {
    return "answer 2";
};
```

Is there a way I can call the function in node.js from C# and access "answer 2"?

Here the error:

```
answer 1
System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]]
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---
> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: No overload for method
'Run' takes '0' arguments
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T
0 arg0)
   at Program.<Start>d__d.MoveNext() in c:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2
013\Projects\snippets\snippets\Program.cs:line 26
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceled
Exceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationTo
ken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013
\Projects\snippets\snippets\Program.cs:line 10
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: What does `Console.WriteLine(deleg)` produce?

Comment: System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]]

Comment: "No overload for method 'Run' takes '0' arguments"  means I think there are missing arguments but the node.js method does not need arguments, so I don't understand what arguments should be send.

Comment: So I'm not an edge.js expert (just trying to help), but it seems like you should be doing something more like: `var result = await task`.  No need to call the run method on the task, the await keyword should invoke the task if it hasn't already been completed.

Comment: Thanks, no error anymore, but no output either, the console seems to hang.

Comment: Hangs at the await I assume?

Comment: yes, after var result = await task it hangs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to adjust your code to the following:

```
var deleg = require.answer2;
Console.WriteLine(deleg);
var task = (Func<object,Task<object>>)deleg; 
Console.WriteLine(task);

var result = await task(1);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I took this directly from the github readme, but essentially calling invoke on the function doesn't actually work like it would with a normal synchronous delegate, instead it just returns control immediately but does not provide a scheduler that can actually run the task.

Comment: I can't get anything for result. It outputs deleg: System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]] and for task: System.Func`2[System.Object,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Object]]

Comment: What does the last line output, or does it still hang at the await?

Comment: this was part of the solution anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be to change module.js to:

```
exports.answer2 = function (input, cb) {
  cb(null, "answer 2");
};
```

I got the answer from [edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/394)